# Can Pandoc be used with Overleaf? Are there any other programs that converts between all kinds of markup formats?

Tags: overleaf, pandoc, linux, online, pandoc-citeproc

Can Pandoc be used with Overleaf? Are there any other programs that converts between all kinds of markup formats? I use Linux and Overleaf editor.

Comment: It depends what you wnat to convert. If you want to use Mardown, then you can use the Markdown package. It enables you to combine Markdown and LateX in one document. If you want to convert LaTeX to HTML, then you can use make4ht, which works with Overleaf.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this. I want to make convert the finished file into doc or docx format. Please help.

Comment: @PramatheshNandan Tom from Overleaf Support here. It's very difficult to export any LaTeX document to common text processor formats like DOC, DOCX or RTF. And neither can it be done in Overleaf, I'm afraid.

Comment: @yo' it is possible to export toODT using this method: https://www.kodymirus.cz/overleaf-html-sample/main.html, but I must admit that it is not really beginner friendly. And debugging Gitgub actions can be much more difficult than local compilation.

Comment: @yo' Hello Tom, does Overleaf support `lwarp` package? If so, it could be done with this package (but I have not tested it).